# TensorFlow not writing events

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Below is a code snippet that I use to monitor events when training a DNNRegressor. I am running from a Jupyter notebook.

During training, I get the following errors in the terminal:

> E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:162] The events file
>   /Users/eran/Genie/PNP/TB/events.out.tfevents.1473067505.Eran has
>   disappeared. E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:131] Failed to
>   flush 2498 events to
>   /Users/eran/Genie/PNP/TB/events.out.tfevents.1473067505.Eran

```
def add_monitors():
     validation_metrics = {'MeanSquaredError': tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_squared_error}
     monitors = learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(valid_X, valid_y, every_n_steps=50, metrics=validation_metrics)
     return [monitors]
      regressor = learn.DNNRegressor(model_dir='/Users/eran/Genie/PNP/TB', 
                                hidden_units=[32,16], feature_columns=learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(X),        
 optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1),       
 config=learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=1))
     monitors = add_monitors()
     regressor.fit(X, y, steps=10000, batch_size=20, monitors=monitors)
```

Any ideas? When opening TensorBoard I do not see any events being recorded

Comment: It looks like the events files aren't being written out. Is there enough disk space? Does the directory in the error message exist?

Comment: There is enough disk space and the directory does exist. I think the problem is with the working through the specific DNNRegressor class because when I set up the writings myself via SummaryWriters it works well. I wonder if anyone has examples of code that writes properly and can be loaded into TensorBoard using the DNNRegressor class

Comment: What do you mean by write it yourself vs using dnnregressor?

Comment: Sorry, was not clear. By writing myself I meant writing the full code of tensorflow that controls the run, i.e., initiates the session, calls session.run to run commands, constructs the tensorflow graph. In DNNRegressor everything is done under the hood as part of this wrapper class, and it seems that this way the tensorboard is not working. If you have an example of DNNRegressor successfully writing logs that are loaded properly by tensorboard that would be most useful

Answer (score 0):

`log_dir=path_to_events_file`

in your code, weather you add some recreate directory code such as `tf.gfile.DeleteRecursively(log_dir);tf.gfile.MakeDirs(log_dir)` . this step must be done before any summary writer, otherwise tf would not be able to find the right event file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows, give the directory like this:

```
model_dir='C:\\Users\\eran\\Genie\\PNP\\TB'
```

Comment: No need. Forward slashes work on Windows. It's best to use forward slashes to be cross platform.